# There is the next task

Tags: construction

Students and a teacher are doing language related exercises. There are 3 of them. The first two have been done and the teacher wants to inform that there is another one because the students seem not to notice it. Would it be correct for the teacher to say:

> **There is the next exercise.**  it should mean "The next exercise exists". I don't mean that the teacher is pointing at it.

I know that "there is the" is a difficult piece of grammar.

Comment: "[Don't forget that] there is another exercise" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: But what if one wants to use the word NEXT? Or maybe it should be "There is a next exercise"?

Comment: Using _next_ seems to me to imply that the students _do_ know that there is another one. However, if the intention is to hurry them along so that all three exercises can be done in the time available, the teacher might say something like "Shall we go on to the next exercise now?"

Comment: Of course, it's a good option, but the point of the question is to sort things out with "there is the next+something".

Comment: I'm trying to explain that _there is the next exercise_ is a valid utterance but not particularly idiomatic.

Comment: OK, is this also possible "There is A next exercise"?

Comment: Again, much less natural than _there is another exercise_.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But realistically, even *There is another exercise* is relatively unlikely in the exact context. If the students don't [necessarily] know there's another exercise, I think the teacher would be much more likely to say *There's [still] **one more** exercise*, because *There is another exercise* tends to suggest *We could do / could have done a **different** exercise* (perhaps we still will do it, or perhaps that was a "now-past" option that we didn't take).

Comment: "There is the next exercise" doesn't really make much sense in this context. It's not ungrammatical, it's just unnatural and not something a native English speaker would say in the context you described. Perhaps try "There is a final exercise to be done".  Since it's the final one, it's obvious from context that it is next in the sequence which is to be done.